# IO exception reading text from a file

Tags: java, io

i'm trying to read text from a text file that I have in my computer in drive `D:`

So, I wrote in Java:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args ) throws IOException{
        FileReader in= new FileReader("D:\nir");
        BufferedReader bin= new BufferedReader(in);
        String text = bin.readLine();
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:ir
  (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at A11.main(A11.java:14)
```

I don't understand what is wrong, since the file exist, the name is correct, perhaps I don't use the correct syntax and commands?

Comment: worong file name. Try with / i mean if your file is ir.txt you should set new FileReader("D:/ir.txt);

Comment: OT: As your class name is Test you should name the file Test.Java and not A11.Java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you should first check if file is exists or not. Also use: **D:\\file.txt**

```
File file = new File(fileName);
if (file.exists()) {
    FileReader rader = new FileReader("D:\\file.txt");      
}
```

Comment: Although I agree with you D:/ is much better I suspect that drive letters will only work in Windows anyway :)

Answer (score 6):

This is the problem:

```
new FileReader("D:\nir")
```

That's "D:" plus a line feed + "ir".

I think you meant

```
new FileReader("D:\\nir")
```

Basically the backslash needs to be escaped in the Java string literal. See [section 3.10.6 in the Java language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#101089) for details.

(As an aside, personally I *wouldn't* use `FileReader` as it always uses the platform default encoding, but that's a separate issue.)

EDIT: An alternative to specifying *either* kind of slash is to use `File`:

```
File file = new File("D:", "nir.txt");
```

That's the most platform-agnostic approach.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thank you for the answer, I still get an error saying that :
"Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: d:\nir (The system cannot find the file specified)", but the file does exists.

Comment: @Nir: You're sure it's just `nir` with no extension etc?

Comment: Oh, the right way to write it was "nir.txt" since it was txt file. Thanks.

Comment: The new File("D:", "nir.txt"); is very nice.

Answer (score 5):

Either escape the slash \\ or change direction of the slash to /.
I much prefer the change of directions.

So you have <strike>two</strike> three possibilitys

```
FileReader in= new FileReader("D:\nir"); // Won't work as \ is an escape character

FileReader in= new FileReader("D:\\nir"); // Escaping, works but not my preferred way

FileReader in= new FileReader("D:/nir"); // I prefer this

FileReader in= new FileReader(new File("D:", "nir.txt")); // Update with help from Jon skeets nice find.
```

Update: Look at your exception it says that  **D:ir** is missing ,look how both the slash and n is missing. Java have transformed your \n to a new line character which obviously was ignored by the FileReader

Comment: I've edited my answer with another alternative - using the File constructor to combine paths.

Answer (score 2):

The following code avoids or eliminates issues with the file separator:

```
import static java.io.File.separator;
```

then you can use the file separator like this:

```
final File test_file = new java.io.File("D:" + separator + "nir");
```